# PHP Imagemagick installation - XAMPP and macosx

Tags: php, macos, installation, imagemagick

Hi how can i nstall Imagemagick extension for XAMPP on a macosx Lion?

I'm trying both googling both searching for past questions about but i can't find anything.

I Only found how to install it on windows :(

Any help appriaciated thanks!!

P.S: i found this http://blog.hubii.com/install-imagemagick-and-imagick-in-xampp-os-x-lion-and-mountain-lion/ but i can't do step 1 since i don't have variants.conf file on my mac :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have Brew yet then get it from here https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Once setup you can use `brew search magick` to see the available packages.

Comment: actually i runned **brew install imagemagick** under **xampp/xamppfiles/bin** hoping it is the right way (i already use homebrew) , so then after installation is finished what i should do? just restar xampp?

Comment: what actually worked for you? I could make it work on php 5.5.3